# Error in element count with Jquery due to click to update

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am counting the number of elements with span class check_box and uncheck_box  When the item with check-box is clicked, its span change to uncheck-box and vice versa. The counter somewhat works, however, I need to click on an element first to trigger it (the count should have already have changed) and then when i click on an element the second time, the count changes. In this instance i should have got two counts but I only get one.

How can this be rectified?

HTML:

```
    <span><a href="javascript:;" class="sort active showall">All</a></span>
    <span><a href="javascript:;" class="sort complete">Completed</a></span>
    <span><a href="javascript:;" class="sort incomplete">Incomplete</a></span>

    <ul class="leftlist">
     <li class="todo" id="1011" itemage="1"><a href="javascript:;"> 
      <a href="javascript:;" class="strike">           
            <span class="check_box cb"></span>

        <p>Option 1 Complete</p> </a>
     </li>

    <li class="todo" id="1011" itemage="1"><a href="javascript:;"> 
     <a href="javascript:;">           
            <span class="uncheck_box cb"></span>

        <p>Option 1 Incomplete</p> </a>
   </li>

   <li class="todo" id="1011" itemage="1"><a href="javascript:;"> 
     <a href="javascript:;" class="strike">           
            <span class="check_box cb"></span>

        <p>Option 1 Complete</p> </a>
   </li>

   <li class="todo" id="1011" itemage="2"><a href="javascript:;"> 
    <a href="javascript:;">          
            <span class="uncheck_box cb"></span>

        <p>Option 2 InComplete</p> </a>
  </li>
```

jQuery

```
var $checkboxes = jQuery('li.todo a'),
    $completeCount = jQuery('.complete-count'),
    $incompleteCount = jQuery('.incomplete-count');

var updateCount = function(){
    $completeCount.text(jQuery('.check_box').length);
    $incompleteCount.text(jQuery('.uncheck_box').length);
};

$checkboxes.on('click', updateCount);
updateCount();
```

Jquery that changes the elements

```
(function($){
        $('li.todo').click(function(){
            if($(this).find('.uncheck_box').length >0){
                var _t=$(this).find('.uncheck_box');
                _t.removeClass('uncheck_box');
                _t.addClass('check_box');
                m_val='1';
                $(this).find('a').addClass('strike');
            }else{
                m_val='0';
                var _t=$(this).find('.check_box');
                _t.removeClass('check_box');
                _t.addClass('uncheck_box');
                $(this).find('a').removeClass('strike');
            }
        var m_key=jQuery(this).attr('id');
            jQuery.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              url: "<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/ajax_get.php",
              data: { meta_key: m_key, meta_value: m_val},
               beforeSend: function(   ) {
                 //jQuery(this).attr("disabled", true);       
              },
              success:function(){}
            })
        });
```

Comment: where is the handler that is changing the `check_box` class

Comment: your counter handler need to execute after that handler is executed

Comment: have updated my code to show the handler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first problem here is the class change handler is registered to the `li` elements(making use of event bubbling) where as the counter handler is registered to the anchor element. So the anchor handler will get executed before the class is updated so attach the click handler to the `li` element instead of anchor element

```
var $checkboxes = jQuery('li.todo'),
    $completeCount = jQuery('.complete-count'),
    $incompleteCount = jQuery('.incomplete-count');

var updateCount = function(){
    $completeCount.text(jQuery('.check_box').length);
    $incompleteCount.text(jQuery('.uncheck_box').length);
};

$checkboxes.on('click', updateCount);
updateCount();
```

also make sure that this event handler is registered after the class change handler is registered

---

A better solution will be is to use a custom event which will be triggered once the class is changed

```
$('li.todo').click(function () {
    if ($(this).find('.uncheck_box').length > 0) {
        var _t = $(this).find('.uncheck_box');
        _t.removeClass('uncheck_box');
        _t.addClass('check_box');
        m_val = '1';
        $(this).find('a').addClass('strike');
    } else {
        m_val = '0';
        var _t = $(this).find('.check_box');
        _t.removeClass('check_box');
        _t.addClass('uncheck_box');
        $(this).find('a').removeClass('strike');
    }

    //trigger a custom event here
    $(this).trigger('updateclass')

    var m_key = jQuery(this).attr('id');
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/ajax_get.php",
        data: {
            meta_key: m_key,
            meta_value: m_val
        },
        beforeSend: function () {
            //jQuery(this).attr("disabled", true);       
        },
        success: function () {}
    })
});
```

then the count handler will listen to the custom event instead of the click handler

```
var $checkboxes = jQuery('li.todo'),
    $completeCount = jQuery('.complete-count'),
    $incompleteCount = jQuery('.incomplete-count');

var updateCount = function(){
    $completeCount.text(jQuery('.check_box').length);
    $incompleteCount.text(jQuery('.uncheck_box').length);
};

$checkboxes.on('updateclass', updateCount);
updateCount();
```